# Ubuntu 10.04: Nautilus type directory name

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

Up until Ubuntu 9.10, I am able to toggle between "typing" mode and "buttons" mode in the UI of nautilus, to select the directory I wish to look at. Personally, I prefer the "typing" mode, which is turned on using the notepad-and-pen icon button.

In Ubuntu 10.04, I cannot find this option in nautilus; however, I find it hard to believe that they have gotten rid of this feature completely, and think it must be buried in some obscure configuration somewhere...

If so, could someone please let me know how to enable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this really annoying too. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> works but only for one time. Here's how to fix it for good:

Open a terminal and run gconf-editor.

Go to Apps > Nautilus > Preferences.

Tick the "always_use_location_entry" box.

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across any "notepad-and-pen" icon in Nautilus before, but I know that you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to have it ask you for a path to view.

Comment: That icon is definitely present in nautilus in Ubuntu 9.10 and before, it is a toggle button on the left edge of the location bar.

Comment: *shrug* I've never run Ubuntu, so...